# C# 4.0 Tasks - Subclassing or Displaying Execution Tree?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task

do you have any advice on how i might visualise a Task Tree? I will be running a large set of long running tasks which each have some child tasks, i want to visualise the running of the execution to the user ideally in a tree / DAG. 
If possible i would like to use the new Task Parallel Library

My first thought is to subclass Task and Name and description feilds, then to try to see if Task has the properties to get a list of child tasks. I could then use GraphSharp.codeplex.com or something similar (any preference?) to visualise the tree.

Any ideas/ Advice?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid subclassing Task (or `Task<T>`).  Doing so will cause TaskFactory to not behave properly, but also potentially lead to a loss of flexibility or a very high amount of required implementation to cover all features.

I would, instead, make a class that schedules and starts the task for you.  This class could be used to generate all of your tasks (even just returning the Task using a factory method).  Internally, it could easily track your graphing information, use continuations on the constructed tasks to track completion or failure events, etc.

Comment: Thanks Reed, I create a task wrapper and visualised it using Graph Sharp with xaml bindings to change the colour of tasks when compelte - everything looks nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Below dotnet component enables us to structure the tasks in `parent-child` relationship and allows us to manage it efficiently. Please refer below link,

[Octopus.TaskTree](https://github.com/gokulegit/Octopus)

`dotnet add package Octopus.TaskTree`

```
// ---------------
// Create a structure of Tasks
// ---------------
IAsyncTask rootTask = new AsyncTask("root");

IAsyncTask childTask_1 = new AsyncTask("Task-1");
IAsyncTask childTask_2 = new AsyncTask("Task-2");

rootTask.AddChild(childTask_1);
rootTask.AddChild(childTask_2);

// --------------
// Set actions
// --------------
childTask_1.SetAction(async (reporter, cancellationToken) => {
    // Simple delay function.
    reporter.ReportProgress(TaskStatus.InProgress, 10, "Started...");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    reporter.ReportProgress(TaskStatus.InProgress, 100, "Finished...");
});

childTask_2.SetAction(async (reporter, cancellationToken) => {
    // Simple delay function.
    reporter.ReportProgress(TaskStatus.InProgress, 5, "Started...");
    await Task.Delay(2500);
    reporter.ReportProgress(TaskStatus.InProgress, 100, "Finished...");
});

// Before starting the execution, you need to subscribe for progress report.
rootTask.OnReporting += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    eventArgs.ProgressValue; // -> this will represent the overall progress
};

// Create and pass the cancellation token
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

// Start the execution concurrently
rootTask.ExecuteConcurrently(cancellationToken, true);

// OR

// Start the execution in series
rootTask.ExecuteInSeries(cancellationToken, true);
```

[image: gif-concurrent-execution]

It provides the flexibility that you can `await` on the root task, start children execution in series or concurrent fashion. You can refer the code snippet given that may give you the clear understanding of the component's purpose.